# Exodus 11:7 - What is the meaning of, "Against none of the children of Israel shall a dog move its tongue"?

Tags: exodus

Exodus 11:7 NKJV

> <sup>**7**</sup> But against none of the children of Israel shall a dog move its
> tongue, against man or beast, that you may know that the Lord does
> make a difference between the Egyptians and Israel.’

What is the meaning of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easy!

Ex 11:7 is part of the story of the 10th plague of Egypt where the eldest son of each family that did not apply the blood to the door posts 9ie, mostly Egyptians) was going to die.  The LORD then prophesies through Moses that:

> Ex 11:4-7 - "About midnight I will go throughout Egypt, and every
> firstborn son in the land of Egypt will die, from the firstborn of
> Pharaoh who sits on his throne, to the firstborn of the servant girl
> behind the hand mill, as well as the firstborn of all the cattle. Then
> a great cry will go out over all the land of Egypt. Such an outcry has
> never been heard before and will never be heard again. **But against
> none of the children of Israel shall a dog move its tongue, against
> man or beast**, then you will know that the LORD makes a distinction
> between Egypt and Israel."

We observe that this prophecy is in three parts:

1. That God will kill the first-born of every family that does not have the blood applied to the door-posts
2. As a result, a great cry will go up from the houses where the first-born sons dies; BUT among the Israelites (those that applied the blood to the door-posts) there will be silence
3. Thus, a distinction is made between the Egyptians and Israelites

Now, the silence among the Israelites (because no body died) is stated in hyperbolic metaphor - not even a dog will move its tongue.  This metaphor is interpreted by various translations as:

- NIV, NLT, LSB: not a dog will bark
- ESV: not a dog shall growl
- BSB: not even a dog will snarl
- NASB: not even a dog will threaten
- etc

That is, there is a contrast between the outcry of the Egyptians vs the silence of the Israelites - not even a dog will move its tongue!

Benson puts it this way:

> **Shall not a dog move his tongue** — A proverbial expression, importing all should be peace and quietness among the Israelites, far
> from any frightful outcry: that in that memorable night they should
> meet with nothing to molest or disturb them.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. That's an interesting metaphor just to say, "there will be peace". I was wondering what a dog's tongue had to do with things. +1. Good answer to a probably foolish question.